# Equivalent for mysqli_fetch_row in prepared statement

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
                    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "Call breakup_api(@inno)");                            
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                        
                    $result = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT @inno');
                    $output = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                    mysqli_free_result($result);                                                

                    var_dump($output);
```

The above is a function to call a stored procedure in php. 
I am able to execute the procedure with the above code, I am trying to convert the above with prepared statement but unable to get the output as the above code does. Can someone tell me what is the equivalent for mysqli_fetch_row($result) while using a prepared statement.

```
$db = new dbConnect();
$this->conn = $db->connect();                          
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("Call breakup_api(@inno);SELECT @inno;");                                                    
$stmt->execute();                          
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysqli_stmt::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

```
$query = "Call breakup_api";// if params  -> Call breakup_api ?, ?, ?

if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($inno);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $inno);
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

`PDO` cannot run multiple queries at once, so move `SELECT @inno` inside of the stored procedure .